# How do I share custom typeDefs and enum in Apollo server?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

Suppose I have two typeDefs, one is user and the other one is a product. In user typeDef, I have a mutation named logout, which when called returns a message. The other typeDef( product ) has a function called add product, which when called again returns a message. I added message typeDef individually in both the typeDefs, but that throws an error **There can be only one type named \"Message\".\n\nField \"Message.message\" can only be defined once**. I am adding screenshots as well for clarity. So How do I share the message typeDefs among both the typeDefs? I hope I have explained my problem.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created one folder and inside that folder, I created message.js typeDefs. I included this file inside my root typeDefs. This approach solved my issues of sharing typeDef across typeDefs.